# How to reference sub-parts of a proposition? (and other queries)

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I want to reference a proposition and sub-parts of a proposition as well.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}\label{p1}
    Let \(f \colon A \rightarrow B\).
    { \renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item A statement about \(f\). \label{p1.1}
        \item Another statement about \(f\). \label{p1.2}
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
We will first prove \cref{p1.1}, then we will prove \cref{p1.2}. We have proved \cref{p1}.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Now, instead of item 1 and item 2, I want prop. 1(1) and prop. (2). Instead of ?? 1, I want prop. 1. How can I achieve that? Also, is it possible to create hyperlinks on the references so that when I click them, I am redirected? I am using XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following help?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{propenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[propenum,1]{%
  label= \sffamily\upshape(\arabic*), % modfiy as desired!
  ref={\arabic*}, % strips formatting!
}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{prop}{prop.}{prop.}
\crefname{propenumi}{prop.}{props.}
\crefformat{propenumi}{prop.~(#2#1#3)}

\newcommand\crefproppart[2]{\namecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}~(\ref{#2})}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}\label{p1}
    Let \(f \colon A \rightarrow B\). Then:
    %{ \renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
        \begin{propenum}
        \item A statement about \(f\). \label{p1.1}
        \item Another statement about \(f\). \label{p1.2}
    \end{propenum}
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
We will first prove \crefproppart{p1}{p1.1}, then we will prove \crefproppart{p1}{p1.2}. We have proved \cref{p1}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: cleveref parts of enumerate in theorem]

Adjust spacing as desired in the definition of `crefproppart` and change formatting in `\setlist` as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I don't fully understand your code, but your answer works.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis: Any particular part of the code giving trouble with understanding it? Are you familiar with the `enumitem` package? If not, take a look at its documentation (or ask here).

Comment: I need to read the documentation of both the `enumitem` and `cleveref` packages.